# Not getting the good result when using WaitForSecond and Mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a block placing script that place a block every 0.15 second, and it work perfectly. The problem is when I try to do the same thing to destroy blocks, instead of destroying a block every 0.3 second, it wait 0.3 second then destroy one block per frame. How can I fix this?

I tried putting it in an other script but it doesn't seem to work either. Weird thing is that if I add Debug.Log("1") inside...:

```
void Place(){
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo)){
        //here
```

...it prints "1" every frame. But if i put Debug.Log("1") inside one of the if `if (hitInfo.collider == up){` it prints "1" every 0.3 second. Sorry for my bad english/explanation

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class placeBlock : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject cube;
    public Collider up;
    public Collider bottom;
    public Collider right;
    public Collider left;
    public Collider front;
    public Collider back;

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
             StartCoroutine(MyMethod());
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
             StartCoroutine(MyMethod2());
        }
    }

    void Place2() {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo)) {
             Destroy(hitInfo.transform.parent.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Place() {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo)) {

        if (hitInfo.collider == up) {
                Instantiate(cube,new Vector3(this.transform.position.x,this.transform.position.y + 1,this.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            if (hitInfo.collider == bottom) {
                Instantiate(cube,new Vector3(this.transform.position.x,this.transform.position.y - 1,this.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            if (hitInfo.collider == right) {
                Instantiate(cube,new Vector3(this.transform.position.x - 1,this.transform.position.y,this.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            if (hitInfo.collider == left) {
                Instantiate(cube,new Vector3(this.transform.position.x + 1,this.transform.position.y,this.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            if (hitInfo.collider == front) {
                Instantiate(cube,new Vector3(this.transform.position.x,this.transform.position.y,this.transform.position.z - 1), Quaternion.identity);}
            if (hitInfo.collider == back){
                Instantiate(cube,new Vector3(this.transform.position.x,this.transform.position.y,this.transform.position.z + 1), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    } 

    IEnumerator MyMethod(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.15F);
        Place();
    }

    IEnumerator MyMethod2(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3F);
        Place2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I note is that you're calling this at each frame.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
             StartCoroutine(MyMethod());
        }
```

This mean you will keep starting the coroutine at each frame (when you press the mouse). I would suggest to move that method outside of the Update Loop, or try to add some boolean flag to avoid calling it at each frame.

You will have something like this in update.

```
void Update()
{
        //you require a bool flag for each element
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !_alreadyPressed) {
             _alreadyPressed = true;
             StartCoroutine(MyMethod());
        }
}
```

And then you reset the bool in the coroutine. Like this.

```
IEnumerator MyMethod()
{
       //you could do something here

       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.15F);

       //do something else
       _alreadyPressed = false;
}
```